# Dual monitors setup capped at 60hz

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, 20.04, framerate

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

My issue:

Dual monitors setup with one 1080p @60hz and another monitor 1440p @144hz. Running on proprietary Nvidia driver 440. Monitor is properly setup at 144hz from display settings and the other one at 60hz.
I can clearly see that only the mouse cursor is running at 144hz but other windows ect.. are stuck at 60hz.
If I disconnect my 60hz monitor, then the issue is fixed and everything is running at 144hz on my main monitor (cursor + windows).

Here is a xrandr output:

```
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 + 144.00*  143.86   119.88    99.90  
   1920x1080    143.85   119.93    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

Trying to find a solution on the internet, I understand that this issue has been around for a while with Gnome Desktop. Is there any news / update on it? Any workaround or bug report to Ubuntu team ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

For people having same issue, found a fix from "KermitTheFrogerino" on Reddit:

First add those 2 lines to `/etc/environment`:

```
CLUTTER_DEFAULT_FPS=144   #Put your refresh rate

__GL_SYNC_DISPLAY_DEVICE=DP-0 #Mine was DP-0
```

Then launch Nvidia X Server settings by typing "nvidia-settings" and then disable "Allow Flipping" in the OpenGL menu.

To apply after every reboot, you just need to launch the "nvidia-settings" menu to apply the settings.

Comment: Disabling "Allow Flipping" caused screen tearing in my case