# Ubuntu 21.10: Disabled "Allow flipping" in NVIDIA X server settings to fix refresh rate problem, but now there is screen tearing

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, 21.10, tearing

I was having the same issue as was described here:
[Dual monitors setup capped at 60hz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252986/dual-monitors-setup-capped-at-60hz)

I did the fix in that thread and it worked, but now my 60Hz monitor has really bad screen tearing on everything (I thought there wasn't screen tearing on the 144Hz monitor, but there was. It seems that's just a limitation with X).

I think I've narrowed it down to "allow flipping". If I have it on, there is no screen tearing, but almost every thing on the 144Hz monitor is stuck at 60Hz.

Is there a way to fix this while keeping the 144Hz monitor at 144Hz?

(I'm on ubuntu 21.10 btw, but it was also happening on 21.04)

Comment: Try force full composition.

Comment: Thanks, full composition fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion of ChanganAuto, checking "Force Full Composition Pipeline" for the 60Hz monitor fixed the screen tearing.

The check box can be found by going to "X Server Display Configuration" in nvidia-settings, selecting the desired monitor, and then clicking "Advanced" at the bottom.